# React Native socket-io - Received data was not a string, or was not a recognised encoding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io-1.0

I am building a proto type for a card game, i have a web version of the game in which i connect to socket.io. it works in fine all major browsers fine.

Code from web app version

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export const connectToSocket = (uid, cb) =>  {
  socket = io.connect(domain, { path: '/api/v1/streams/socket/', query: 'token='+uid})

  socket.on('connect', function(){
      console.log('Socket connected')
  });

  socket.on('message', function(data){
      cb([null,JSON.parse(data)])
  });

  socket.on('connect_error', err => cb([err, null]))
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){cb([400, null])});
}
```

however when i try to connect from react native i get the error

> Received data was not a string, or was not a recognised encoding.

React Native code

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
let socket

export const connectToSocket = (uid, cb) =>  {
   socket = io.connect({path: '/api/v1/streams/socket/', query: `token=${uid}`})
}
```

I have read all the posts on stackoverflow and git and it seems to me the solution that works for almost everyone is forcing websocket transport rather than pooling. For example:

```
   socket = io.connect({path: '/api/v1/streams/socket/', query: `token=${uid}`, transports: ['websocket']})
```

however this solution does not work for me. I know the backend works fine as the web app version can connect. also when i send the connection request with react native, the server side logs what it should.

Although the server side works fine, here is the code for the connection event

```
func (s *sockets) socketHandleConnectionEvent(so socketio.Socket) {
  token := so.Request().URL.Query().Get("token")
  uid, err := g.f.verifyToken(token)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Could not verify token")
      return
  }

  //Connect user
  s.clients.set(uid, so)

  // Check if player is currently in a room
  inRoom, roomID, err := IsPlayerInRoom(uid)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error: Checking player is in room")
  }

  if inRoom == true {
      fmt.Println("REJOINING ROOM")
      so.Join(roomID)
      SendCurrentGameState(roomID, uid)
      return
  }

  gameID, gameStarted := GenerateRoom(uid)
  so.Join(gameID)
  SendCurrentGameState(gameID, uid)

  if gameStarted {
      s.addTimer(gameID, uid)
  }

  return
}
```